# Maps from $V\otimes V^*$ to the underlying field

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V\in \operatorname{Vect}(k)$ I was asked to consider if the evaluation map was the only map from  $V^*\otimes V$ to $k$.  My question is, is it correct for me to rephrase this question to be, can you find a map $\phi:V^*\otimes V \to k$ that is independent of any choice of basis?  An answer to my rephrased question is something I think I can solve.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. A linear map is always independent of a choice of basis (it's just the matrix that depends on it).

Comment: @manthanomen Well, to consider what the evaluation map does to elements of $V^*\otimes V$ you might consider what it does to the basis elements, i.e. the pure tensors.  Sorry if this isn't clear, I admit I'm just trying to find a direction to proceed on the original question I was asked.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Yes, maps from the tensor product are usually defined by specifying what they do to basis elements.

Comment: Would $\phi = 0$ do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps $V^*\otimes V \to k$ are the same thing as elements of $(V^*\otimes V)^*$. Since this is not the zero vector space (assuming $V \neq 0$), it has more than one element. If your field is infinite, say $k = \mathbb R$ or $k = \mathbb C$, then $(V^*\otimes V)^*$ is also infinite. This proves that the evaluation map is not the only map.

Comment: If the field and the dimension of $V$ are both finite, the set $(V^* \otimes V)^*$ is finite.

Comment: @MooS Thanks for the correction. I've fixed it.

Comment: Cool thanks; that answers my question as asked.  However, I believe I need to ask for clarification on what I was asked to consider originally.  I probably am missing a bit of the context that the questioner assumed I had a handle on.